# Coffeescript run function or read variable

Tags: coffeescript

Say I have either

```
msg = "Saved Successfully"
```

or

```
msg = -> "Saved #{@course.title} Successfully"
```

Is there anyway to elegantly get the value of msg without knowing whether it's a function or a regular variable rather than doing

```
success_message = if typeof msg is 'function' then msg() else msg
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's a CoffeeScript shorthand you can take advantage of:

```
f?()
```

is equivalent to

```
f() if typeof f is 'function'
```

which means that you can write

```
success_message = msg?() ? msg
```

This works because `msg?()` has the value `undefined` if `msg` isn't a function.

**Caveat:** This will fail if `msg()` returns `null`, setting `success_message` to the `msg` function.

Really, if you're going to do this in your application, you should write a utility function:

```
toVal = (x) -> if typeof x is 'function' then x() else x
successMessage = toVal msg
```

You could even attach `toVal` to the `Object` prototype if you're feeling adventurous..